# Any examples for Windows containers hosted in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Was anybody able successfully deploy any sort of Windows container to Service Fabric (even plain vanilla microsoft/iis or something)? If you did would you mind sharing your config files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, read these blog posts [here](https://loekd.blogspot.nl/2017/01/running-windows-containers-on-azure.html) and [here](https://loekd.blogspot.nl/2017/01/running-windows-containers-on-azure_10.html) for more information on how to get started. It's a walkthrough with some troubleshooting tips.

(Note: because it's in preview now, things may change.)

Comment: I did search quite extensively for any real examples before posting here for real world examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When I deploy a windows container via service fabric in windows server 2016 using the dev cluster setup or multi node, the docker service stops running so I can't verify if the docker container is running. Does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Create environment variable called "docker_host", point it to tcp://localhost:2375 and it will work.